# MySQL copy row to another table when column matches a value AND doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I have a bit of a MySQL conundrum, I'm designing a form for a venue for uses with Wi-Fi and COVID etc, other stuff.

Now, it's a PHP form which writes into a database, the info is kept for 30 days until it's purged (30 days from the date stamp). This runs on an event, every day (and works fine).

I wanted to add in a checkbox to say add them to a mailing list so I figured I needed another table to copy the info for the subscribers that obviously doesn't get purged for use later.

Currently I have this query that works:

```
INSERT INTO table2
    SELECT *
    FROM table1
    WHERE mailing = 'on';
```

But I really need to copy the row where mailing='on' AND the email address doesn't exist. It's this part that I'm really stuck on, is it possible to do this within the same query?

Comment: *But I really need to copy the row where mailing='on' AND the email address doesn't exist.* Add according `.. AND NOT EXISTS (..)` - what a problem?

Comment: Thanks for the tip although, this presents me with another issue which I can't get any further on " Unknown column 'table2.email' in 'where clause' " it definitely exists.

Comment: The subquery in WHERE EXISTS must use another copy of `table2` as is data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need in something like

```sql
INSERT INTO table2 ( {columns list} )
SELECT {columns list}
FROM table1 t1
WHERE mailing='on'
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM table2 t2
                   WHERE t1.email = t2.email );
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Just so I understand the "SELECT NULL" is what you were referring to about "The subquery in WHERE EXISTS must use another copy of table2 as is data source"?

Comment: @RT050 *another copy of table2 as is data source* is `FROM table2 t2` in subquery's text. `SELECT NULL` means nothing - EXISTS check the row presence only, ignoring the values in it.